# pointer arithmetic : char pointer as a member of a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I took an example `structure` from K&R (page: 133) and tried a few `pointer` arithmetic on a `pointer` to an `array` of `structure`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
// struct example from K&R
struct key {
    char *word;
    int count;
}keytab[] = {
    "auto",0,
    "break",0,
    "const",0,
    /*.....*/
    "case",0
};
int main () { 
    struct key *ptr1 = keytab;
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(struct key));

    //check1
    printf("%s\n",ptr1++->word); //1
    printf("%s\n",ptr1->word);   //2

    //check2
    printf("%s\n",++ptr1->word);  //3
    printf("%s\n",++ptr1->word);  //4

    //check3
    printf("%s\n",ptr1++->word);  //5
    printf("%s\n",ptr1->word);  //6 ??
}
```

output:

```
8
auto
break
reak
eak
eak
const
```

I could understand the output of `3rd` and `4th` `printf` with the help of operator precedence.

But when it comes to `5th` and `6th` `printf`, how `ptr1` has incremented in here ? output of the program shows similar behaviour as with `1st & 2nd` `printf`s.  If `ptr1` increments in step of one struct size (here `8` bytes) then how it aligns itself to the starting of a `keytab[2]`.

I might have understood wrong or this last query may be invalid, please explain !

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If ptr1 increments in step of one struct size (here 8 bytes) then how it aligns itself to the starting of a keytab[2].

But `ptr1` is *always* pointing to an element of keytab. It's not allowed to point part-way through an element, and that never happens.

The reason you see `reak`, and then `eak`, is that the keytab entry *pointed to by* `ptr1` has been changed in-place.

That is, `++ptr1->word` doesn't change `ptr1` *at all*. You can check - just print its value before and after. That expression changes the value of `word` *inside* your keytab. After line #3, `keytab[1].word` has changed (been incremented) so it points to `"reak"`.

When you finally increment `ptr1` again (just after #5 is printed), you're still incrementing it from `&keytab[1]` to `&keytab[2]`. The fact that you modified the inside of `keytab[1]` doesn't affect that at all.

> I could understand the output of 3rd and 4th printf with the help of operator precedence

It seems you correctly realised most of this, but overlooked that changing `ptr1->word` doesn't affect the value of `ptr1` itself.

Comment: `but overlooked that changing ptr1->word doesn't affect the value of ptr1 itself.`. Yes, I thought `ptr1` is moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

So, the 3 and 4 prints increment ptr1->word. After they are executed, ptr1->word points to "eak".

Print 5 prints that unmodified value first and then increments ptr1, which then points to the next word in the list, "const".

This all is about operator precedence, as you stated but also about the effect of prefix and postfix ++ operator. The side effect of those is the same, but the first returns the new value, while the second the old one.

Comment: when you said `"which then points to the next word in the list"` So, irrespective of where `ptr1` is pointing earlier `ptr1++` will always advance to the starting location of the next array element (here `keytab[2]`). Am I correct?

Comment: No, as told above ++ptr1->word did not change the value of ptr1. ptr1++ will always result in ptr1 = ptr1 + 1, so the previous value of ptr1 matters.

Comment: Yes, I got my mistake

Answer (score 1):

This expression:

```
++ptr1->word
```

does not increment `ptr1` pointer. Due to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) it's grouped as `++(ptr1->word)`, because `->` operator binds more tightly than prefix `++`. What it means is that it increments the `word` member of currently pointed object of the struct.

Comment: I was expecting `ptr1` pointing to somewhere in the middle of `keytab[2]` member string `"const"` after `5`th `printf`. But this is not the case here. So irrespective of where `ptr1` is pointing earlier `ptr1++` will always advance to the starting location of the next array element (here `keytab[2]`) ??

Comment: @Debashish: Exactly. The type of `ptr1` is pointer to `struct key`, so it always advances to the next element of the array `keytab`.